# Where should I put already in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Where should I put already in this sentence ?

> I've been playing with it for a few hours already, but still no luck.

For me it seems ok to put before verb **been** or before **hours**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on what you wish to emphasize the position of "**already**" will vary.

**Mid position**

> We usually put **already** in the normal mid position for adverbs (between the subject and the main verb, or after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb, or after be as a main verb).

*We don’t use **already** between a verb and a direct object.*

- I've been playing already with it for a few hours, but still no luck. (**Wrong**)

**End position**

> We can use **already** at the end of a sentence for greater emphasis or to show greater surprise. This is especially common in informal speaking.

**Front position**

> Less often, we put already in front position (before the subject). We don’t often put already in front position in informal speaking.

[**Cambridge Dictionary**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/already)

So with your sentence it can be either in the *mid position* or the *end position*:

- I've **already** been playing with it for a few hours, but still no luck.
- I've been playing with it for a few hours **already**, but still no luck.

Comment: I think you're quite right that *on average*, placing ***already*** at the end of the ***clause*** gives greater emphasis than using the "standard" position (between subject and primary verb). Of course, there's also the "Yiddish" habit of appending it to the entire ***sentence***, as in *I've been playing with it for a few hours, but still no luck **already**.* That version always sounds a bit "affected" to me, as does "fully fronting" the adverb: *Already I've been playing with it for a few hours, but still no luck.*

Comment: I would avoid both the fronted position and the Yiddish style of placing **already**.

Comment: Dang! You speak Yiddish like a natural already! :)

Answer (score -2):

It should be

> I have **already** been playing with it for a few hours, but still no luck.

Comment: Not only. It can take up a position in between different sections.