# "Already" in the middle or in the end of the sentence?

Tags: word-choice

I've been thinking about it for a long time and I'm wondering where should I put already in the sentence?

For example:

> 1. Hey are your arms already trembling?
> 2. Hey are your arms trebling already?

I heard that already at the end of the sentence gives a greater emphasis, but what do you think about this example? Did I make any mistakes in it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this previously posted [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/131016/where-should-i-put-already-in-this-sentence). It's a great explanation of the word's usage.